# How to change windows default resolution using regedit?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, resolution, regedit

I'm trying to change de default resolution a Azure VM using REGEDIT.

So, I tried to change DefaultSetting.XResolution from 1024 to 1440 and
DefaultSetting.YResolution from 768 to 900.

It seems to work fine, but when I reboot the machine, the registers turns to 1024x768 again. And it happens everytime I try to change and reboot

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on changing the default display resolution on Azure VM, you can vote up [this feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/37957429-add-ability-to-set-vm-resolution-on-creation) and [Why is not possible increase or change display resolution in Azure VM](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/6022dcce-f6a7-4a3c-a69e-a3a204a0734f/why-is-not-possible-increase-or-change-display-resolution-in-azure-vm?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows).

[image]

As a possible solution, you can refer to [this blog](https://mark0203.blogspot.com/2018/04/powershell-how-to-overcome-azure-vms.html).